# FindBugs: What is the best way to solve "Method ignores results of InputStream.skip()"?

Tags: java, findbugs

I have the following code:

```
final Response res = this.origin.act(req);
for (int count = req.body().available(); count > 0;
    count = req.body().available()) {
    body().skip(count);
}
return res;
```

FindBugs reports this problem in ***body().skip(count)***:

> [FindBugs: L B RR: ignores result of java.io.InputStream.skip(long)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SR_NOT_CHECKED)

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You have linked to the findbugs description of why ignoring the return value of skip can cause problems. Which part of the explanation are you stuck on?

Comment: @beresfordt I know what is the problem.... I'm talking about the best way to solve the problem..  how do you suggest that the problem could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This method ignores the return value of java.io.InputStream.skip() which can skip multiple bytes.  If the return value is not checked, the caller will not be able to correctly handle the case where fewer bytes were skipped than the caller requested.  This is a particularly insidious kind of bug, because in many programs, skips from input streams usually do skip the full amount of data requested, causing the program to fail only sporadically. With Buffered streams, however, skip() will only skip data in the buffer, and will routinely fail to skip the requested number of bytes.

To avoid the findbugs warning, and so the bug that ignoring the return value could mask, you need to check the return value matches the number you requested to skip; eg

```
final Response res = this.origin.act(req);
for (int count = req.body().available(); count > 0;
    count = req.body().available()) {
    long skippedBytes = body().skip(count);
    if (skippedBytes != count) {
        // do something
    }
}
return res;
```

The 'something' that you should do if they don't match is a choice you need to make dependent on the situation this is being used in; you might want to throw an exception, you might want to log and carry on, or you might want to perform some sort of fallback, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

@beresfordt Thanks. I think I found a better solution using [ByteStreams.skipFully(req.body(), count);](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#skipFully(java.io.InputStream,%20long))

```
final Response res = this.origin.act(req);
for (int count = req.body().available(); count > 0;
    count = req.body().available()) {
    ByteStreams.skipFully(req.body(), count);
}
return res;
```